# Error creating bean entityManagerFactory in Class SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface PersistenceProvider

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting this exception
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-12-02T00:12:02.819+05:00 ERROR 17996 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1166) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:940) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at fhir.dataexport.DataExportApplication.main(DataExportApplication.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
... 16 common frames omitted

pom.xml looks like

`

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.1.5
 

fhir
data-export
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
data-export
data-export

<java.version>21</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web
3.1.5


org.apache.camel.springboot
camel-spring-boot-starter
4.1.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Camel JAXB for XML processing -->
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version> &lt;!&ndash; Use the latest version &ndash;&gt;
    </dependency>-->

    <!-- Apache Camel Jackson for JSON processing -->
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version> &lt;!&ndash; Use the latest version &ndash;&gt;
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-structures-r4</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.5</version> <!-- Use the latest version for FHIR R4 -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-base</artifactId>
        <version>6.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAXB Runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAXB Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Activation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>72.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-jpaserver-base</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).